# How to scrape country-bound website

Tags: python, proxy, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying scrape site with scrapy.
But have redirecting to page error 404, as I am not from that country. 
If use proxy, I have the same.
My code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

from v4.items import Product


class AcerOfficeworksAuSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "acer_officeworks_au_py"

    url = 'https://www.officeworks.com.au/shop/SearchDisplay?searchTerm=acer&storeId=10151&langId=-1&pageSize=24&beginIndex=0&sType=SimpleSearch&resultCatEntryType=2&showResultsPage=true&searchSource=Q&pageView='

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(self.url, self.parse, meta={'proxy': 'http://97.77.104.22:3128'})

    def parse(self, response):
        print response
```

Result:

```
2017-03-23 12:49:29 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://wc-prod-joomla.s3.amazonaws.com/404/404.html> from <GET https://www.officeworks.com.au/shop/SearchDisplay?searchTerm=acer&storeId=10151&langId=-1&pageSize=24&beginIndex=0&sType=SimpleSearch&resultCatEntryType=2&showResultsPage=true&searchSource=Q&pageView=>
2017-03-23 12:49:34 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://wc-prod-joomla.s3.amazonaws.com/404/404.html> (referer: None)
<200 https://wc-prod-joomla.s3.amazonaws.com/404/404.html>
2017-03-23 12:49:34 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Response, if use curl with proxy:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

HTTP/1.1 302 Security Redirect
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: 0
Location: https://wc-prod-joomla.s3.amazonaws.com/404/404.html
Pragma: no-cache
transfer-encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

What can I try yet to make it work?

Comment: Where are you?  The original URL loads fine for me from Switzerland.   Can you load the URL in your browser?

Comment: @MartinBonner I'm from Ukraine. In browser using vpn it's loading good.

Comment: If you are using chrome, then use "menu > more tools > developers tools" and select the "network" tab to see all the requests that are going on.  I'm sure other browsers have similar.  You obviously need to make sure that you are using the vpn for your curl/scrapy request.  I'd start by fetching from www.iplocation.net and see what you get back.

Comment: @MartinBonner Solved. I just found another one proxy ip.

Answer (score 0):

The product data is in this url :

```
https://www.officeworks.com.au/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/OWPriceView?storeId=10151&catalogId=10551&nc=true&productId=90235%2C90237%2C90239%2C504502%2C532522%2C559534%2C450004%2C495002%2C315544%2C582002%2C90229%2C112392%2C450006%2C536530%2C536532%2C536534%2C536536%2C597502%2C605514%2C396502%2C423002%2C536518%2C559532%2C610502
```

this page use JavaScript to fetch data from the URL above.

```
In [1]: url = '''https://www.officeworks.com.au/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/OWPriceView?storeId=10151&catalogId=10551&nc=true&productId=90235%2C90237%2C90239%2C504502%2C5
   ...: 32522%2C559534%2C450004%2C495002%2C315544%2C582002%2C90229%2C112392%2C450006%2C536530%2C536532%2C536534%2C536536%2C597502%2C605514%2C396502%2C423002%2C536518%2C
   ...: 559532%2C610502'''

In [2]: fetch(url)
2017-03-23 20:01:00 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-03-23 20:01:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.officeworks.com.au/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/OWPriceView?storeId=10151&catalogId=10551&nc=true&productId=90235%2C90237%2C90239%2C504502%2C532522%2C559534%2C450004%2C495002%2C315544%2C582002%2C90229%2C112392%2C450006%2C536530%2C536532%2C536534%2C536536%2C597502%2C605514%2C396502%2C423002%2C536518%2C559532%2C610502> (referer: None)

In [3]: import json

In [4]: json.loads(response.text)
Out[4]: 
[{'bulkbuy': True,
  'hasContractPrice': False,
  'partNumber': 'ACC120',
  'price': '$357.00',
  'priceRange': [{'maximumQuantity': '2.0',
    'minimumQuantity': '1',
    'value': {'currency': 'AUD', 'value': 357.0}},
   {'maximumQuantity': '',
    'minimumQuantity': '3',
    'value': {'currency': 'AUD', 'value': 314.0}}],
  'priceRangeExclTax': [],
  'productId': '90229'},
```

Comment: I think problem not in JavaScript. It's problem in connection to site, but not in scraping website

Comment: From my country I have redirect to https://wc-prod-joomla.s3.amazonaws.com/404/404.html